# parse error syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE

Tags: php

I cannot seem to figure out why I keep getting this error on line 17. The call stack says
`Location : 27`, that is route function and `Location : 0` and that is `{main}( )`.

```
<?php
define("true-access", true);
session_start();
ob_start();
function get_option_enabled($option) {
    if ($option == "store") {
        return "store/controller.php";
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function route() {
    $option = empty($_GET["option"]) ? "store" : $_GET["option"];
    $view = empty($_GET["view"]) ? "list" : $_GET["view"];

    //get files to include from database
    if ($controller = get_option_enabled($option)) {

        include_once('components/' . $controller);
        controller_route($view);
    } else {
        echo "404";
    }
}

route();

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: ($controller = get_option_enabled($option)) <- Double Equals for comparison in PHP. Like you have here: ($option == "store")

Comment: He's not comparing, he's assigning. And that wouldn't produce a parse error. Most likely the problem here is in the include

Comment: He IS comparing, full line is here: if ($controller = get_option_enabled($option)) { And I didn't say it was his problem, just pointing out a problem with his code...which is why it is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: He is comparing, this is why using if. If you assigns, then you do not use if. Anyway, this code is valid, the problemm will be in the include.

Comment: @Mark I don't think you understand. If `get_option_enabled` returns false he wants to go to the `else` block. It's common to go `while($row = $mysqli_res->fetch_assoc())`. In this case I'm assigning `$row` a value and if that value is false-y I want the loop to fail. One final nail in the comparison coffin... `$controller` has no assigned value so it would be `NULL`, meaning the `if` would always fail.

Comment: For those who don't get @Machavity try this http://codepad.org/noHqcSOC also try changing return value of `get_option_enabled` to false. That is perfectly fine. otherwise why would he include it in the next line.

Comment: I understand now. I would never wrote code that way because my IDE throws an error whenever I try to do an assignment like that, which is why I now assume no one ever does that. That'll teach me to listen to my IDE...